# Zend framework autoloader strange behaviour

Tags: zend-framework

I am migrating some project code to ZF-Boilerplate and am encountering some strange behaviour with the autoloader.

I have these lines in the application.ini

```
autoloadernamespaces[] = "App_"
autoloadernamespaces[] = "Boilerplate_"
;autoloaderNamespaces[] = "DCH_"
autoloadernamespaces[] = "Elastica_"
autoloadernamespaces[] = "EasyBib_"
```

note that ;autoloaderNamespaces[] = "DCH_" is commented out.

Later, in my bootstrap, I have the following line as a test:

```
$test=new Elastica_Facet_Range('testing');
```

That works fine, but if I uncomment the previously commented line, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Elastica_Facet_Range' not found in /vagrant/www/myswap/application/Bootstrap.php on line 43
```

It's driving me mad because in means I can't get my namespaces working.

When I step through Zend_Loader_Autoloader with the line commented out, the protected variable *namespaces contains : Zend* , ZendX_, App_, Boilerplate_,Elastica_ and EasyBib_

With the line uncommented *namespaces contains (also if I move the DCH* line to the end of the list): Zend_,ZendX and DCH_

If I move the DCH_ line to the start of the list *namespaces contains : Zend* , ZendX_, App_, Boilerplate_,Elastica_ and EasyBib_

I have added the following to the bootstrap to make it work, but it is a hack and I'm not happy with it:

```
$autoloader = \Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

        $autoloader->registerNamespace('DCH_');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just taking a wild guess but have you tried rearranging the lines in you application/ini so that DHC_ is last?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have updated my original post with more details about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why this works, but it does. I can see NO difference whatsoever. I commented out those lines and copied the originals from the other project, and it works??

```
;autoloadernamespaces[] = "App_"
;autoloadernamespaces[] = "Boilerplate_"
;autoloaderNamespaces[] = "DCH_"
;autoloadernamespaces[] = "Elastica_"
;autoloadernamespaces[] = "EasyBib_"

    autoloaderNamespaces[] = "App_"
    autoloaderNamespaces[] = "DCH_"
    autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Boilerplate_"
    autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Elastica_"
    autoloaderNamespaces[] = "EasyBib_"
```

Comment: Might have something to do with the uppercase "N" in "autoloadernamespace" ... maybe Zend_Config chokes on it?

Comment: @ChrisR that's probably the case. I bet if we looked at the code it would work with either all camel case or all lower case but to mix them is to ask for trouble. In this instance Zend standard is camel case.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I'm sure you're right...mystery solved!